# unable to install ruby gems on ec2

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm tring to install the r10k ruby gem on my puppet server but all i ever get back from rubygems.org is:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
bad response  429 (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=text)
```

What gives? i can install it on my mac or non ec2 hosted servers just fine. Is there a workaround i can use to forcibly install it?

Environment:

ubuntu: 16.04

gems: 2.2.5

ruby: 2.1.9p49I

Answer (score 0):

nvm apparently rubygems.org couldn't handle the dependancies for whatever reason. Just installed them all manually. yay dependency managers....